# QT Creator build and rebuild

Tags: qt, build, qt-creator

I have 2 projects with Qt-creator C++. Let's call it project A and project B. Project A works fine. But project B is strange. Last week when I tried to debug it, it stuck. I re-saved the .pro file (not changing anything) and it works. But now every time I **build** and debug (which is **build** and **run**), qt does **rebuild** it all. It creates moc_blabla.o again every time I build it. So when I debug project B, qt **rebuild** it and run, not **build** and run. But in project A everything works fine. Project A.pro and project B.pro have the same architecture, no special configuration, all is default. Is there something wrong I did in project B? Is there a way I can do a normal build in project B again?

Comment: Try to run qmake on your project. Right click on the project in the projects pane and select `Run qmake`.

Comment: I did and it worked. But how can I run it? Since run is build and run.

Comment: Maybe you messed with the build steps and or order in Project settings?

Comment: Maybe you are mixing shadow build dirs and source dir builds. Qt Creator by default uses shadow build (checkbox under Projects), and it is a good idea too. Try `make clean distclean` in source dir and see if it does anything (from,command prompt).

Comment: I don't think so. Because these 2 projects have the same project setting. :(

Answer (score 0):

Qt Creator sometimes gets things mixed up, for instance, when you have hand-edited the project file. If your project acts strangely then close all projects and editors in Qt Creator and then delete all intermediate files (*.obj, *.o, ...) and outputs (*.exe, *.dll, *.lib, *.dylib, ...) produced from your project. Also, delete the .pro.user file(s). The last step will force Qt Creator to configure the project anew (and thus create a new .pro.user file).

All of the above might be achieved through make clean or Qt Creator cleaning steps but I always do it by hand.